# What functionality and API may be affected by DST and TZ changes? What to test?

Tags: date-time, timezone, checklist, daylight-saving-time, quality-assurance

As the 2014 RTZ datetime changes weren't implemented smoothly by SharePoint, let's brainstorm on what has and could go wrong with another change like that.

So the question is: what test cases to verify?

There are multiple points to check, so I suggest that we post different test cases as separate answers and vote for each that we consider more or less important, and afterwards compile them into an actual checklist.

Comment: Have you changed TimeZone.xml manually?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but the question is about QA checklist of WHAT TO TEST to verify correct transition.

Comment: There's valuable food for thought here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices

Answer (score 0):

**Test Case 1**

Check **Date** field values such as **Created** and **Modified** in test items. When something goes wrong, date or time may be recorded mistakenly shifted forward or backward.

**Tip:** *Write equivalent DateTime values to string-based **Title** and affected **Date** fields to compare after implementing changes or rolling back.*

Check **Date Only** field values created before implementation of the change - in case of time shift of 1 hour backward, these may corrupt the values by nudging the dates backward as well. This may be critical for certain business applications.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Case 2**

Check that SharePoint Designer declarative Workflows can be published correctly.

**Tip:** *In case TIMEZONE.XML or RGNLSTNG.XML **[TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ms459863(v=office.15).aspx)** elements don't have valid **Name** attribute values, workflow publishing may fail.*

Answer (score 0):

**Test Case 3**

Make sure that immediate and scheduled alerts arrive timely.

**Tip:** *Use the **Alert me** action in a list or library and create a scheduled alert for a specific time and compare the planned and actual delivery times.*

Answer (score 0):

**Test Case 4**

Test any client side functionality that might rely on date-time matching such as JavaScript.

**Tip:** *Watch out for `new Date(year,month,date,hour,minute)` and `new Date(string)` in your scripts. Test anything that depends on DateJS or MomentJS for example.*

Answer (score 0):

Check dates in future created before timezone changes. For example: Date in DateTime column with value 1 dec 2014 15:58 in item which was created 1 sep 2014 16:00

Answer (score 0):

Third party tools may also suffer from such changes. For instance, Nintex Workflow schedules may be affected.